# What is the default MySQL 5.7.18 root password?

Tags: mysql

I've struggled with this problem for years and I always end up having to mess around for a long time with different reset methods or a combination of other crap.

On a new MySQL server install, what's the default root password? It's not `admin`, `root`, blank etc... I have no `/var/log/mysql.log` file to look for a temporary password:

```
brandon@brandon:~$ ls -la /var/log/mysql/ total 112 drwxr-x---  2 mysql adm     4096 Jun 24 21:14 . drwxrwxr-x 16 root  syslog  4096 Jun 24 21:14 ..
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm    66416 Jun 24 22:15 error.log
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     1768 Jun 24 21:10 error.log.1.gz
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     1755 Jun 20 17:05 error.log.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     2231 Jun 15 20:53 error.log.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     3204 Jun  6 21:42 error.log.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     2347 Jun  5 09:24 error.log.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 mysql adm     8289 Jun  2 18:33 error.log.6.gz
```

I looked at the mysql config file (which is now at `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` and not `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`??) and found that the logs to `/var/log/mysql/mysqld.log` were disabled by default. Enabled them hoping for a miracle to no avail. No temporary password in there.

Starting MySQL with `skip-grant-tables` (per [the MySQL docs on the subject](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)) to force-reset the password isn't working now either.

Running `sudo mysql_secure_installation` and setting the password didn't reset the password either.

How do I get in?

Comment: Depends if it asks you when you install it in terminal, else it's null

Comment: It didn't ask and null, `<blank>` etc... Are not working

Comment: how are you trying to access mydql? If no password is needed, you don't need to specify the -p parameter

Comment: Tried with `mysql -uroot -p` and `mysql -uroot`. Access denied.

Comment: The password will be written (during installation) to the error-log, so have you checked the `error.log`-file or any `.log` or `.err`-file in your data directory? It should contain the text `temporary password` somewhere.

Comment: I checked `error.log` but didn't check the other files. I will look there

Comment: Just to make sure: I meant to also check the zipped logs - you will need the log from the time you installed the server. Since it seems you currently have no usable database anyway, you can also simply delete the content in your data directory and reinitialize the database, which will give you a new temporary password (in the error log, and it is actually displayed on the console too).

Comment: I checked all 6 zipped logs to no avail. I am going to delete the data directory. How do you mean "reinitialize the database"?

Comment: I completely removed mysql-server, deleted the data directory, deleted the config directory etc... and re-installed. I was prompted for the password this time around.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mysql -uroot
```

will allow you to login, then you'll need to create a user for normal connection (not root).

```
create user 'user'@'localhost' identified by 'user1234';
grant all on your_database.* to 'user'@'localhost';
select host, user from mysql.user;
```

then try to access with your new user

```
mysql -u user -p
```